# What is the difference with on one set statement in do loop and multi-set statements?

Tags: sas, set

I am learning the skill of using double set statement and got a trouble in the following code:

```
data test1;
do i = 1 to 2;
    set sashelp.class;
end;
run; 

data test2;
    set sashelp.class;
    set sashelp.class;
run;
```

Test1 has 9 observations(all of the even rows) and Test2 has 19 observations, can somebody explain this for me?

Comment: I modify "do i = 1 to 2;" to "do i = 1 to 3;" and find Test1 just have 6 observations (one in every three rows of sashelp.class). I think I know how Test1 was generated but still don't know the difference between Test1 and Test2.

Comment: May the answer is  **the first data step has 1 row indicator and the second has 2 row indicators**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAS `output` statement writes out observations to your output data set. When no explicit `output` statement is used (as in your data steps) an implicit `output` at the end of the data step outputs the current observation to the output data set.

In your first data step the `do` loop causes the `set` statement to be executed twice, the first time reading obs #1, the second time reading obs #2. The loop finishes and the next statement is `run`, so the implicit `output` outputs the current observation which is #2. The next iteration of the data step causes the `do` loop to read obs #3 and then #4, so the last obs (#4) is output, and so on until the end of the data set.

The second data step executes the first `set` statement reading in obs #1, then it executes the second `set` statement, reading obs #1 from that input data set, **overwriting** the current observation. The implicit `output` causes this obs to be written out. The data step reiterates causing the same to happen to obs #2, and so on until all 19 obs are read and output.

Inserting some diagnostics can help understand what is happening, e.g submit the following and check the log:

```
data test1;
   do i = 1 to 2;
      set sashelp.class;
      putlog 'In loop: ' i= name=;
   end;
      putlog 'About to output: ' name=;
run;
```